# MongoDB - Should I index tags with tag names or ObjectId?

Tags: mongodb, tags, indexing, key, objectid

As title, I am considering which key is better: tag names or ObjectId. Since tag names are unique, it OK to use them as index. What should I concern on choosing keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the tag name in your case is good , as you do not have to create extra index for _id as mongodb automatically create the index for _id field. The only concern you should have that it remains all the time unique :) . If you create tag as another key and then index it , you will waste the space for the _id index key. So better use the tag as _id

Comment: In firsts glance, specifying `name` as the primary key is ok. But in this way the code will be less expressive. Also I am using Backbone.js, consider the following code `var tag = new Tag({_id:'tag name'}); tag.save();`, the `save` call will launch a **PUT** req instead of **POST**, because the `_id` exists. So I decide to store both `_id` and `name`, where `_id` is the original `ObjectId`.